# Multi-line style comments causing XML documentation warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xml-documentation

I have many multi-line style comments in a C# project and when the project option is set to output a XML documentation file they all trigger the warning *XML comment is not placed on a valid language element*. This behaviour is observed in Visual Studio 2010.

Short of changing all these comments to single-line style comments what can I do to prevent these warnings from being triggered?

Reduced example:

```
public class Foo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Does something.
    /// </summary>
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        /**
         * Do something interest here.
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Something to do with the double star? That's like a doc-comment in Java... change it to `/*` instead of `/**`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just remove the second `*` on the first line of the comment.

C-style XML doc comments are opened with `/**`.

Comment: I see, only `/**` triggers the warning, any other amount of `*` in the first line does not trigger the warning. Thanks @SLaks and @applechewer.